# Any performance issues forcing eager evaluation using count in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

Commonly I see `Dataset.count` throughout codebases in 3 scenarios:

1. logging `log.info("this ds has ${dataset.count} rows")`
2. branching `if (dataset.count > 0) do x else do y`
3. force a cache `dataset.persist.count`

Does it prevent the query optimizer from creating the most efficient dag by forcing it to be eager prematurely in any of those scenarios?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** 1) and 2) can be usually avoided but shouldn't harm you (ignoring the cost of evaluation), 3) is typically a harmful [Cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) practice.

**Without `cache`**

Calling `count` alone is mostly wasteful. While not always straightforward, logging can be replaced with information retrieved from listeners  ([here is and example for RDDs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37496650/9613318)), and control flow requirements can be usually (not always) mediated with a better pipeline design.

Alone it won't have any impact on execution plan (execution plan for count, is normally different from the execution plan of the parent anyway. In general Spark does as little work as possible, so it will remove parts of the execution plan, which are not required to compute count).

**With `cache`**:

`count` with `cache` is bad practice naively copied from patterns used with RDD API. It is already disputable with `RDDs`, but with `DataFrame` can [break a lot of internal optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49798098/9613318) (selection and predicate pushdown) and technically speaking, [is not even guaranteed to work](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Will-count-always-trigger-an-evaluation-of-each-row-tp21018p21024.html).

Comment: Count doesn't change how cache works, but cache changes how count does.

Comment: `dataset.persist.count` is still a good way to trigger caching right ?